# how to sqldump a subset of data from each table for an entire database in mysql

Tags: database, mysql

Let's say there is a production `DB` `P` and a local `DB` `L`. I would like to have a subset of the data from `P` and restore them in to `L`.

I know One can easily `sqldump` a subset of data from a table in `mysql`.
But what if it is a `DB` with, say, 50 tables? Can one just easily `sqldump` all the tables for the first, say, 1000, records?

As a bonus, assuming it is `star schema`, is it possible to use a major table, which connects to most other tables, and select the first 1000 records for that table and retrieve the subset of data that are foreign keyed for the 1000 records correspondingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's an easy way to do this all at once. The only way to subset the data is with the `-w` option, but it will try to use the same `WHERE` condition for all tables. You could do it in two steps:

```
mysqldump -w 'id < 1000' dbname mastertable > mastertable.sql
mysqldump -w 'master_id < 1000' dbname child1 child2 child3 ... > children.sql
```

This assumes all the child tables use the same name for their foreign key.

You can simplify the second command to:

```bash
mysqldump --ignore-table=dbname.mastertable -w 'master_id < 1000' dbname > children.sql
```

if all the other tables in the database are children.

Answer (score 1):

For a similar problem I found something called Jailer: http://jailer.sourceforge.net/  It extracts interconnected data starting from a root table you choose without breaking foreign key relations. It is of course possible that you have more than one root table connecting all the others so select them separately.

Like you want only 5 cities from a city table, it detects country table is connected to city table and dumps countries of those 5 cities too etc.